# Elastic Search, MongoDB: Mongo-Connector Custom Mappings and Settings

Tags: mongodb, indexing, elasticsearch, mapping, settings

I have implemented the mongo-connecter with ElasticSearch and MongoDB. It works well where when a document is added to the MongoDb it is automatically added to ES with automatic mapping. My question is what if I want to add analyzers, filters, and custom mappings to an index. Such as n-gram, lowercase filter, term-vectors. ElasticSearch does not allow updating mapping and setting so how would I go about this?

Comment: Are you talking about this project? https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector. Note that you can definitely update mappings anytime. Also you can [update index settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#update-settings-analysis) (analyzers, etc), but you need to close the index first and then re-open it.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out the solution to my question. In my scenario the mappings and settings for Elasticsearch must be set before you begin adding documents into MongoDb. This way you will be able to do custom analyzers such as ngram analyzers with mongo connector. Once you add documents to MongoDb it will be synced up in ES with it's mappings and settings.

To give you a more detailed answer I'll provide a concrete example. In a scenario where you have an API connected to a MongoDb as a primary datasource but want to add ElasticSearch for its fast searching functionality you can use Mongo-Connecter to keep MongoDb and ElasticSearch in sync. But what if I want to add custom settings and mappings? Well as I'm sure you know you cannot edit/update indexes that have already be set. You would have to close the index, make changes, and re index the data to get those updates. My solution to this issue is by having the api have a settings and mappings file. Here I added settings such as filters and ngrams and mappings to match the format of the data that will be stored in the MongoDb. On startup the api makes a call to ElasticSearch creating an empty index from our mappings and settings. Then the api can post data into MongoDb knowing that the index in Elasticsearch has already been created. The main point here is that you need to start up and set the index in Elasticsearch before you begin inputing data into the MongoDb.

I did hear of another solution where you can use templates in Elasticsearch to have data inherit settings based on unique criteria. You can read more about it here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you please improve answer a little bit, add more information and advises. I want to give you a bounty, but answer is not very clear